# Shouldn't we be able to migrate Excel questions to SuperUser.com?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, moderation, migration

Currently we have no way of migrating Excel questions anywhere. They would be off-topic in most of the cases for http://stackoverflow.com, so we shouldn't migrate them there. However, it seems that https://superuser.com/ is a place where [lots of Excel questions get answered](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) -- maybe we should be able to migrate such questions there?

Comment: We *can* migrate questions to SU, (and [have](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222261/dynamic-yearly-monthly-charts-in-excel), quite recently).

Comment: @Glen_b it is not available in `off-topic because... -> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only moderators have the ability to migrate questions to any site.  SE also imposes a limitation on the number of default sites made available in the migration dialog.

The solution is to flag the thread and recommend a migration target.

(In controversial cases, mods can contact mods at the intended destination site to ask them in advance whether they would accept the migration.)

Comment: Out of curiosity - and what is this limitation? Is it 3?

Comment: @amoeba That's my recollection.

Comment: @amoeba, I don't believe it's 3.  On [SO] 5 default sites are listed (including us). There isn't really room for more than 5 to be listed. Moreover, I think there was some meta.SO discussion of changing what the options were, implying that something needed to be removed to add something else. It's possible the limit for SO is different than for us, though.

Answer (score 3):

We (at least, we as a site) can migrate questions to SU, (and [have](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222261/dynamic-yearly-monthly-charts-in-excel), quite recently).

I see this when I choose close/off-topic/"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network":

[image]

Since you don't see it, I am not sure what privilege level this comes at though (20K? diamond mod?)  .... [Scortchi says that it's diamond-mod. I believe this recollection is correct.]

You can always close as off-topic and flag. Several high rep users frequently flag to suggest migration* (not all such requests turn into migrations, though - sometimes there are reasons not to -- e.g. it's off topic at the suggested destination; or it's actually on-topic here).

[One such user flagged [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224487/calculate-matrix-exponential-in-excel) not very long after you commented there.]

Comment: For me only the first three options are available, so I guess it needs some additional privileges.

Comment: @Tim Probably diamond-mod. You can always close as off-topic and flag.

Comment: I remember getting that when becoming a mod. Think we have to ask SE devs to include it in the list - if it's a frequent enough migration path to merit that (& there might be something like you're only allowed 3).

Comment: Even if we could justify (and get) an additional site to migrate to, I wouldn't think SU would be our next most common site.

Comment: @Glen_b it wouldn't for sure, but Excel is (unfortunately) pretty common software, from time to time such questions appear and this would make migration smoother -- as with questions dealing with other software.

Comment: I am above 20k and I do not see this option so @Scortchi must be right.

Comment: I always thought it was strange that we have a comment that Open Data is a place to ask for data, but can't auto-migrate -- I guess that is a consequence of the limitation on the number of migration destinations.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial Isn't it also because OpenData is in beta? I recall that only mods can migrate to betas, as a general rule.

Comment: @Glen_b What *would* be our next most common migration destination, then?

Comment: @amoeba Ah, crap, yes, you are right. I think this is the second time someone has pointed that out to me. Oops.

Comment: @amoeba Well I'd have guessed Economics or Open Data, with SU competing with Software Recommendations for third (among those not already in the list)... however, I am no longer confident that's an accurate impression.

Comment: @amoeba I found [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/70419/post-migrations-by-destination-volume) but I don't think it can be right. It would seem to suggest there's only been a little over 100 migrations altogether -- and there have certainly been more than 2 to SU

Comment: A second query with the same result [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/113952/of-posts-migrated-away-by-destination)... still don't believe it can be accurate

Comment: @Glen_b I found this one http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.tridion/query/472000/find-all-questions-sucessfully-migrated-away-from-a-site it says 2358 posts were migrated to SO; isn't it too many?..

Comment: By the way, both OpenData and Economics are in beta so I don't think they can be targets for routine (non-mod) migration.

Comment: @amoeba correct... though fact that they're roughly ll in the same ballpark for volume would also suggest that there's no strong urgency for adding SU to the list - it wouldn't save much. I wonder if we have any regular SU users here -- it might help us get more sense of what we could successfully migrate